# Load XML into TreeMap

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML config file that has just one parent and one child. This will always be like this and never change. It looks something like this:

```
<parent>
   <child1>test</child1>
   <child2>123</child2>
</parent>
```

I want to use java DOM (`org.w3c.dom.Document`) to parse the XML into a TreeMap so that I can access the attributes as keys/values. I'm guessing I'd need to create a for loop that scans through the XML and adds the key (parent) and value (child) line by line?

Comment: Did you already try anything? What was the result?

Comment: The why don't you start with learning DOM processing and worry about storing the result into a `TreeMap` later?

Comment: I don't think `TreeMap` does what you think it does.  The `Tree` part describes the algorithm used for finding the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can traverse the XML document using `JAXP APIs`, you don't need to know the structure or node names in advance

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
NodeList nodeList = doc.getChildNodes();
```

and you can iterate on document and get the nodes and attributes

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();

//...
```

}